# Detecting 404 Somehow

Tags: bash, ssh, chromium

I keep my PC running at home. Sometimes, when I'm at work, my PC can't load the pages that I want to load. I have to ssh to it, and reboot/restart browser. It's really annoying and I'm trying to find an easier way to do this. I thought about getting a screenshot and somehow try to check if it looks like a 404 page that I took screenshot before. But that may use my system resources a bit much.

I tried to catch the title of the page with `xdotool`, but it fails.

Is there a way of detecting 404 pages? I'm using chromium-browser with Ubuntu. Those webpages are not accessible from my computer because of my internet connection/computer. The webpage is always on, but sometimes, because of connection problems, browser shows 404 with that tiny dinosaur. This is my xdotool code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/xdotool
a=`xdotool search "http://a.com is not available - Chromium" | head -1`
if [[ $a ]]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "nope"
fi
```

Comment: "Those webpages are not accessible from my computer because of my internet connection/computer. " hmmm that makes not sense in relation to checking a website? Is it not enough to check your internet connection itself? For instance: "ifconfig" shows you if you have an IP addres.  "sudo ethtool eth0" checks your cable for instance.

Comment: Oh uh. I deleted my nonsense output messages and messed this one. In my original one, I have a ".

Comment: @Rinzwind But here's the problem: The internet can and 90% of the time comes back after I get a 404. So, when I check the internet connection, everything is cool. But after I got a 404, and when my connection comes back online, this algorithm fails. Sorry. I think I can't explain clearly.

Answer (score 3):

How about `wget`?

Three examples: one to a not existing page, one to an existing page you are not allowed to download and one that works.

wget https://askubuntu.com/testfor404

```
--2014-05-09 22:06:20--  https://askubuntu.com/testfor404
Resolving askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)... 198.252.206.24
Connecting to askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)|198.252.206.24|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-05-09 22:06:21 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

wget https://askubuntu.com/reputation

```
--2014-05-09 22:07:11--  https://askubuntu.com/reputation
Resolving askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)... 198.252.206.24
Connecting to askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)|198.252.206.24|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-05-09 22:07:11 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

wget http://askubuntu.com

```
--2014-05-09 22:07:36--  https://askubuntu.com/
Resolving askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)... 198.252.206.24
Connecting to askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)|198.252.206.24|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 69629 (68K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

100%[======================================>] 69.629       257KB/s   in 0,3s   

2014-05-09 22:07:36 (257 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [69629/69629]
```

---

That command could be expanded to show "true" or "false" in case the output shows "ERROR 404: Not Found".

---

The option `--delete-after` will delete the index.html after downloading it. `--spider` flag will check the page header/status without downloading.

Comment: Using the `--spider` flag will check the page status without downloading.

Comment: But all those webpages are all accessible. I get 404 because of me/my computer/my internet connection. And browser stucks in 404 page because of it. I'm updating my question now. Thank you, but this does not solve my problem.

Comment: if you do not have an internet connection active all of these will show a 404 :) Even websites that are active.

Comment: no, 404 is when you connect to the webserver but this hasn't the page requested. Is a server side message, and I really doubt it would appear if you have connection problems @user1652575.